# How to convert Mongo bson binary to something like Guid or JUUID?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I am trying to decode an _id that I retrieved from this query.

```
type fcc struct {
   ID  bson.RawValue   `bson:"_id"`
}

func GetFromfccId(fccId string) {

result := fcc{}
conn := auth.Authenticate()
collection := conn.Database("something").Collection("else")

err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"fccId":fccId}).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

  fmt.Println(result.ID)
}
```

and that#s what I get from the mongo driver

> {"$binary":{"base64":"wk8bWKTMKUMWhSuvVLdahQ==","subType":"03"}}

How can I convert it to something like JUUID or Guid?

I can't do anything with this binary format.

I have tried to use uuid.UUID in the struct but it breaks when I try to decode.

Thank you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to do it.

If the data is being saved as binary (type 3) in mongo you can retrieve this data as LUUID changing the type to primitive.Binary.

```
type fcc struct {
    ID  primitive.Binary   `bson:"_id"`
}
```

And that's it, it will return to you a LUUID in bytes, something like this.

```
{3 [75 77 158 195 190 205 183 38 234 126 239 224 5 182 53 133]}
```

The first byte means the type, 3 in this case is binary and the rest is your data.

But if in this case you receive a JUUID (that's my case) you gonna need to convert this JUUID to LUUID to be able to query this data in mongo.

There is no built function or library in go to do this (at least I couldn't find it).
You can accomplish this just changing the order of the bytes like this.

```
func JuuidToUuid(juuid string) []byte{

    var byteShift []byte

    u, err := uuid.FromString(juuid)
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for x := 7; x > -1; x-- {
       byteShift = append(byteShift, u[x])
    }
    for x := 15; x > 7; x-- {
      byteShift = append(byteShift, u[x])
   }

   return byteShift
}
```

But this is still not enough for mongo to understand because this is not a valid binary, you still needs to encode it as binary to be able to add the first byte with the type (3 in this case)

To encode you can use the bson library.

```
id := converter.JuuidToUuid(businessPremisesId)
binaryId := primitive.Binary{
    Subtype: 3,
    Data:    id,
}
```

and that's it, now you have a valid binary type to query.

```
err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id":binaryId}).Decode(&bpData)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [mongo official go library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver), change the _id value of type to [primitive.ObjectID](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID)

If you want a string representation of this ObjectId, you may use its [ObjectID.Hex()](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID.Hex) method to get the hex representation of the ObjectId's bytes.
Something like,

```
objectID := mongoId.(primitive.ObjectID).Hex()
```

Comment: if I keep as bson and change to primite.ObjectID

`ID  primitive.ObjectID  bson:"_id"`

and it returns 

**error decoding key _id: cannot decode binary into an ObjectID**

if I change to json I can apply your logic but it returns

**000000000000000000000000**